# How to use Three.js with MediaPipe to make an AR web app

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, mediapipe

my friend and I are trying to make an AR web app for a University Workshop. We want track the hand and put on the wrist a 3D Object. We have 2 problems:

- how we can use the webcam on threejs as a scene?
- how we can take the wrist landmark and put something on it?

Thanks for your suggestions

We have create the hands detection taking the webcam streaming video as a input, then we have create a scene and a camera for threejs but they work separately.

UPDATE: we have this code, that works but not Three.js:

```
import {
  HandLandmarker,
  FilesetResolver
} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision@0.10.0";
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.132.2';

const video = document.getElementById("webcam");
const canvasElement = document.getElementById("output_canvas");
const canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
const cubeContainer = document.getElementById("cube-container");

let results = {};

let handLandmarker;
let webcamRunning = false;

const enableWebcamButton = document.getElementById("webcamButton");
enableWebcamButton.addEventListener("click", toggleWebcam);

const initializeHandLandmarker = async () => {
  const vision = await FilesetResolver.forVisionTasks(
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision@0.10.0/wasm"
  );
  handLandmarker = await HandLandmarker.createFromOptions(vision, {
    baseOptions: {
      modelAssetPath: `https://storage.googleapis.com/mediapipe-models/hand_landmarker/hand_landmarker/float16/1/hand_landmarker.task`,
      delegate: "GPU"
    },
    runningMode: "LIVE",
    numHands: 1
  });
};
initializeHandLandmarker();

async function toggleWebcam() {
  if (!handLandmarker) {
    console.log("Please wait for HandLandmarker to load.");
    return;
  }

  webcamRunning = !webcamRunning;

  if (webcamRunning) {
    enableWebcamButton.innerText = "DISABLE PREDICTIONS";
    await startWebcam();
    initializeThreeJs();
    predictWebcam();
  } else {
    enableWebcamButton.innerText = "ENABLE PREDICTIONS";
    stopWebcam();
  }
}

async function startWebcam() {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
  video.srcObject = stream;
  await video.play();

  const { videoWidth, videoHeight } = video;
  canvasElement.width = videoWidth;
  canvasElement.height = videoHeight;

  //Imposta dimensioni del div cube-container in base alle dimensioni del video
  cubeContainer.style.width = video.videoWidth + 'px';
  cubeContainer.style.height = video.videoHeight + 'px';
}

function stopWebcam() {
  const stream = video.srcObject;
  const tracks = stream.getTracks();
  tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
  video.srcObject = null;
}

async function predictWebcam() {
  if (!webcamRunning) return;

  if (!handLandmarker) {
    console.log("Please wait for HandLandmarker to load.");
    return;
  }

  const startTimeMs = performance.now();
  results = await handLandmarker.detectForVideo(video, startTimeMs);

  canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
  if (results.landmarks) {
    for (const landmarks of results.landmarks) {
      drawConnectors(canvasCtx, landmarks, HAND_CONNECTIONS, {
        color: "#00FF00",
        lineWidth: 5
      });
      drawLandmarks(
        canvasCtx,
        landmarks,
        { color: "#FF0000", lineWidth: 2 },
        video.offsetWidth,
        video.offsetHeight
      );

      updateCubePosition(landmarks);
    }
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(predictWebcam);
}

//________Three.js_________

function initializeThreeJs() {
  //Crea scena
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  //Crea camera prospettica
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, video.videoWidth / video.videoHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  //Crea un renderer Three.js
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
  renderer.setSize(video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
  renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  renderer.domElement.style.top = '0';
  renderer.domElement.style.left = '0';
  cubeContainer.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  //Crea il cubo
  const cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
  const cubeSize = 0.1;
  const cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize);
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeMaterial, cubeGeometry);
  scene.add(cube);

  // Log posizone sfera
  console.log('Cube position X:', cube.position.x);
  console.log('Cube position Y:', cube.position.y);

  // Funzione per posizionare il cubo sul polso
  function positionCubeOnWrist(wristPosition) {
    // Trasforma le coordinate 2D del polso in coordinate 3D della scena
    const normalizedX = (wristPosition[0] / video.videoWidth) * 2 - 1;
    const normalizedY = -((wristPosition[1] / video.videoHeight) * 2 - 1);

    // Aggiorna la posizione del cubo
    cube.position.x = normalizedX;
    cube.position.y = normalizedY;
  }

  // Aggiorna la posizione del cubo ad ogni frame
  function updateCubePosition(landmarks) {
    if (landmarks && Array.isArray(landmarks) && landmarks.length > 0) {
      const wristPosition = [
        landmarks[0].landmark[0].x * video.videoWidth,
        landmarks[0].landmark[0].y * video.videoHeight
        ];
        positionCubeOnWrist(wristPosition);

    }
  }

  // Funzione per il rendering della scena
  function render() {
    updateCubePosition();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  render();

}
```

The error in console is the following:

```
three.js:2744 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'center')
    at Sphere.copy (three.js:2744:29)
    at Frustum.intersectsObject (three.js:7224:15)
    at projectObject (three.js:15269:47)
    at projectObject (three.js:15292:7)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (three.js:15181:5)
    at render (script.js:163:14)
    at initializeThreeJs (script.js:167:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.toggleWebcam (script.js:46:5)
```

Comment: Are you using MediaPipe to get the hand landmarks? That should result in an array of 3D points. For example: `hand = [{x:10,y:20,z:12}]`, perhaps in a different form. Be sure to check that MediaPipe returns 3D coordinates and not 2D points. Once you have those points from MediaPipe, you could draw a little globe in ThreeJS at those coordinates to see if everything works correctly.

Comment: Yes, we are. In fact, we have taken the landmarks coordinates, normalized and used for the cube position. But nothing appears, I think that MediaPipe and Three.js don't communicate between each other. I have this error in log console: three.js:2744 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'center')
    at Sphere.copy (three.js:2744:29)
    at Frustum.intersectsObject (three.js:7224:15)
    at projectObject (three.js:15269:47)
    at projectObject (three.js:15292:7)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (three.js:15181:5)
    at render (script.js:163:14)... etc

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have clean `x,y,z` coordinates without any other surplus information from MediaPipe. For example:

```
points = [
   {x:10, y:10, z:10},
   {x:16, y:16, z:20},
   {x:22, y:20, z:23}
]
```

Now you are free to use this `x,y,z` info however you want. To place an object at those points:

```
let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 )
let material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
let cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )
scene.add( cube )

cube.position.set(points[0].x, points[0].y, points[0].z)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer! Very useful to understand what it's happening on the code. But it doesn't work. I'm scared that Three.js and MediaPipe cannot comunicate each other. In this moment I have 2 canvas on the HTML: one for capturing the camera, one to draw the hands landmarks. I want to add to one of them a cube, or a 3D object on the wrist and see in realtime, like an AR web app. Our initial concept was create a web app that show on the wrist vital informations like heartbeat, oxygen in the blood and so on. But with Three.js and Mediapipe seems impossible. Any suggestion?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you need to "clean up" the mediapipe data. Once you have "clean" `x,y,z` coordinates, it doesn't matter in which library you use it. Can you show the result of the mediapipe query?